# how can i achieve noise texture/material as show in below image

Tags: texturing, materials

"I tried using a noise texture, but I'm not getting the desired result.
while i apply same texture result if fine but on this object only getting straight lines texture

[image]

[image]

[image]

file link : https://we.tl/t-dP0jig7tM6

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 1):

It looks a bit like a *Voronoi Texture* (in *Smooth F1* mode), plug it into a *Bump* map (inverted) that you plug into the *Normal* input of the *Principled BSDF*:

[image]

Comment: Sir, I applied the same thing, but I'm not getting the same result as you are (only getting a straight line texture effect). Please, if you have time, could you open the .blend file and check? When I apply it to a normal object like a cube, the result shows the same as in your image. @moonboots

Comment: Thanks, sir! @moonboots, now I got the result. I increased the scale in the y-direction, and the results are fine